# How to go to another html page with onsubmit without erasing data

Tags: javascript, html

My code will not work as I am trying to get my values to submit to another html page while keeping them. If I put a `return false;` it will go to the next HTML page without keeping the values; and if I don't have that it keeps the values without going to the next page. Please help if this is actually possible and if it is not please give me other suggestions.

```js
document.getElementById('form').onsubmit = function(e) {
  class matches {
    constructor(name1, name2) {
      this.name1 = name1;
      this.name2 = name2;
    }
  }
  const p1 = document.querySelector('#person1').value;
  const p2 = document.querySelector('#person2').value;
  const pair = new matches(p1, p2);
  console.log(`${pair.name1} and ${pair.name2}`);
  return false;
};
```

```html
<div id="main-header">
  <h1>Ship It! &#10085;</h1>
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="title">
    <h1>What is your magical Ship?</h1>
    <form action="pages/lodaing.html" id="form"> <input type="text" placeholder="Your Firstname" id="person1" autocomplete="off">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Their Firstname" id="person2" autocomplete="off"><br>
      <a href="/pages/lodaing.html"><button id="button" type="submit"><a href="/pages/lodaing.html"onclick="">&#9829</a></button>
      </a>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I need to add anything else please inform me. Sorry if I am not using the correct terms (I am new to the work).

Thank you!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: your html  is wrong  ( form > a > button > a )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove the code for `onSubmit` event listener
2. add name property to your `input` elements

**HTML [Current page]**

```
<form action="pages/lodaing.html" id="form"> 
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your Firstname" name="person1"
                    autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Their Firstname" name="person2" autocomplete="off"><br>
    <button id="button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

3. You can write below code to get the input values of both inputs on next page

**JS [Next page]**

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
    var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

var person1 = getParameterByName('person1');
var person2 = getParameterByName('person2');

console.log(person1,person2);
```

**Explanation**

What's happening here is,

The form on current page [HTML] submits a get request on 'pages/lodaing.html'

When a form is submitted using the 'Get' method [which is default] the new page is loaded with form values as query parameters created from form inputs [?param1=value1&param2=value2]

So, we wrote some script to get exact param values from the url on next page

Inside Javascript function, We pass the param name for which we need to get the value submitted

The function parses the url string for the pattern & searches for the key we pass & return the value for same

Hope this was easy to understand for you!

Comment: Glad to help, Please also upvote the answer, would be helpful

Comment: I just started I cannot upvote for some reason but it says it will be counted but not displayed.

Comment: Sorry to be a bother but if you have enough time may you please edit an explanation in your answer. I am really new to the coding scene and I am pretty lost. Thank You!

Comment: I have added more explanation in the answer

Comment: Thank you I will not bother you anymore!

Answer (score 0):

Making your form send values through a GET method (which is the default) you can use the Javascript **URLSearchParams** object on the next page, this object has all you need to handle your passed data. With this object you can avoid using the Javascript code on your first page, unless you need specific data checks and/or manipulation of course.

Checkout **URLSearchParams** [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).

**NOTE:**
*In your code you have to specify attribute name for the input fields whose value you want to pass to the other HTML page, as written the form is going to send nothing.*